# symfony2 doctrine datetime ignores time?

Tags: symfony, datetime, doctrine, query-builder

Hi I am trying to get dates after datetime('now)

My query is not checking against the time value.

I have the following dates :

- 2015-09-03 18:00:00
- 2015-09-03 18:00:00
- 2015-09-10 16:30:00
- 2015-09-13 09:00:00
- 2015-09-13 09:00:00
- 2015-09-13 09:00:00
- 2015-09-13 09:00:00
- 2015-09-13 09:00:00
- 2015-09-13 09:00:00
- 2015-09-13 09:00:00
- 2015-09-13 12:05:00
- 2015-09-13 12:05:00
- 2015-09-13 12:25:00
- 2015-09-13 12:25:00
- 2015-09-13 12:25:00
- 2015-09-13 16:30:00
- 2015-09-14 15:10:00
- 2015-09-14 18:20:00

It seems to ignore the time completely
I can get it to return anything after the 14th, i would expect it to return anything where the time is greater than my startdate (`2015-09-14 12:40:39`)

```
public function getRemainingKeysForTimeframe($timeframeID){
        $startDate = new \DateTime('now');
        $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('q')
            ->select('q')
            ->andWhere('q.timeframeID = :timeframeID')
            ->andWhere('q.date >= :start')
            ->setParameter('timeframeID', $timeframeID)
            ->setParameter('start', $startDate->format('Y-m-d h:i:s'));
        return $queryBuilder;
    }
```

Comment: your startdate is (2015-09-14 12:40:39)? seems to me there is no date later than that (they are all set to 2015-08...)

Comment: I just copied and pasted the range from the db, have updated my question in in clude more references

Comment: Have you tried using H instead of h in your format?

Comment: managed to fix it, i was getting data from a table where the date field was date not dateTime

Answer (score 1):

Inject the actual `\DateTime` object as a parameter in your query builder:

```
->setParameter('start', $startDate);
```

**not**

```
->setParameter('start', $startDate->format('Y-m-d h:i:s'));
```